# Adding numbers to dates in text boxes

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime, textbox

Hi I could do with some help with some coding in Excel vba.. I have 2 text boxes, the first is a box which will have a number in it such as 1, 2 or 3 etc. This will represent how many days the actual date is incorrect.  I also have a text box containing a date.  I am simply trying to add or subtract (depending on a selection in a third box) the date figure to this number.  In the excel worksheet, I just simply do =sum(date+n) and the answer is there, but not sure how I should be doing this with the text boxes. I’m sure it is a simple thing that I am missing!

I’m a currently using this:

```
If daydifflist= “Normal” then
Correctdate = Logdate

Elseif daydifflist =“Ahead” Then
Correctdate = val(logdate) + val(daydifference)

Elseif daydifflist =“Behind” Then
Correctdate =val(logdate) - val(daydifference)

End if
```

If let’s say I wanted to add 5 (daydifference) to `28/06/2020` (Logdate) then I get the answer 33 and not `03/07/2020`.

I’m sure it’s a simple thing I’m missing!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: In vba use Cdate() but also remember that vba is us-en centric and the date must follow that format.

Comment: Thanks Scott.. I’ve edited a bit to show you my issue!

Comment: 1. `Val` only returns the number until the first non numeric character.  So you are adding 28 and 5 which is 33. Use Cdate and Clng.  2.  The date will need to be parsed as it is text and in vba the dates need to be in  US-EN format, `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: for example: `cdate(split("28/06/2020","/")(1) & "/" & split("28/06/2020","/")(0)& "/" & split("28/06/2020","/")(2))`

Comment: or: `dateserial(split(logdate,"/")(2), split(logdate,"/")(1),split(logdate,"/")(0))`

Comment: Thanks Scott the cdate and clng work a treat.